# Getting error ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended when I use 2 insert statement in talend

Tags: talend

I am using below query

```
Insert into table1(id , empid,avtive) values (22,24,'Y')
Insert into table1(id , empid,avtive) values (23,29,'Y')
```

Comment: try putting a ";" between the insert commands

Answer (score 0):

Talend will not split the commands when encountering a newline character. You need to add a `;` to separate the 2 commands.